# Android selector & text color

Tags: android, textview, android-selector

I want a simple `TextView` to behave the way `simple_list_item_1` in a `ListView` does. Here's the XML:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" android:focusable="true"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background" />
```

Everything works except for the text color that (expectedly) doesn't change in focused state. How do I make it change to `textAppearanceLargeInverse`?

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the xml file, it's here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/res/color/bright_text_dark_focused.html

Answer (score 83, accepted):

And selector is the answer here as well.

Search for bright_text_dark_focused.xml in the sources, add to your project under res/color directory and then refer from the TextView as

```
android:textColor="@color/bright_text_dark_focused"
```

Comment: I think this has changed to "primary_text_dark_focused.xml".

Comment: This just blew my mind. I've been handling things with listeners to change text color all this time. Jaw on floor. Brilliant!

Comment: Never thought that selectors also work for textColor, super easy.

Comment: I tried this with the root Layout of a view that I made for my `ListFragment`, and ended up with a [bunch of errors](http://pastebin.com/zzTkn1L5). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: we can't use @android:color/white over there..  displaying content assistance not available when I press Ctrl +  space

Comment: OMG all these years I've been just so living in the dark! Damn! it's so good! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 446):

I got by doing several tests until one worked, so:
res/color/button_dark_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

res/layout/view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="EXIT"
       android:textColor="@color/button_dark_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: without the android:drawable the app crashes with this selector xml

Comment: @neufuture: you need to use `android:textColor="@color/button_dark_text"`

Comment: There is a document describing the color state lists: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: As curiosity, it also workis when the text, button or any item has been activated, e.g, for list item. <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />

Comment: Should the selector really reside under `res/color` folder?

Comment: Although hex notation is supported. Please take note hex notation with alpha is not(e.g  #10FFFFFF  white 50% transparency). Using reference to color resource is better(i.e @color/your_color_resource) in this respect.

Comment: @mr5 and to all trying to implement this: **Yes** it is important to place the selector under `res/color`. Only there you can add a color (instead of a drawable) to the selector! Otherwise you will get an inflating exception.

Answer (score 36):

In order to make it work on selection in a list view use the following code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

Apparently the key is `state_activated="true"` state.

Comment: Don't forget to place this file under res/color folder

Comment: This should be made the correct answer. Works 100%

Answer (score 34):

Here's my implementation, which behaves exactly as item in list (at least on 2.3)

res/layout/list_video_footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_video_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="98px"
        android:text="@string/more"
        android:textColor="@color/bright_text_dark_focused"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

res/color/bright_text_dark_focused.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:color="#ccc"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: This worked well for me, and in my case worked quite well for adjusting the highlighted/unhighlighted colors for my TabHost implementation

Answer (score 7):

In `res/color` place a file "text_selector.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green" />
</selector>
```

Then in `TextView` use it:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@color/text_selector"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />
```

And in code you'll need to set a click listener.

```
private var isPressed = false

private fun TextView.setListener() {
    this.setOnClickListener { v ->
        run {
            if (isPressed) {
                v.isSelected = false
                v.clearFocus()
            } else {
                v.isSelected = true
                v.requestFocus()
            }
            isPressed = !isPressed
        }
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    textView.setListener()
}

override fun onPause() {
    textView.setOnClickListener(null)
    super.onPause()
}
```

Sorry if there are errors, I changed a code before publishing and didn't check.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example of selector. If you use eclipse , it does not suggest something when you  click ctrl and space both :/ you must type it.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"  />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
```

You can look at for reference;

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 2):

I always used the above solution without searching more after this. ;-)

However, today I came across something and thought of sharing it. :)

This feature is indeed available from API 1 and is called as **ColorStateList**, where we can supply a color to various states of Widgets (as we already know).

It is also very well documented, [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)

Answer (score 2):

If using TextViews in tabs this selector definition worked for me (tried Klaus Balduino's but it did not):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!--  Active tab -->
  <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:color="#000000" />

  <!--  Inactive tab -->
  <item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `setOnFocusChangeListener`? Within the handler, you could change the text appearance.

For instance:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            ((TextView)v).setXXXX();
        } else {
            ((TextView)v).setXXXX();
        }
    }
});
```

You can then apply whatever changes you want when it's focused or not. You can also use the ViewTreeObserver to listen for Global focus changes.

For instance:

```
View all = findViewById(R.id.id_of_top_level_view_on_layout);
ViewTreeObserver vto = all.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onGlobalFocusChanged(
        View oldFocus, View newFocus) {
        // xxxx
    }
});
```

I hope this helps or gives you ideas.

Comment: I've gone this way initially but text color didn't change for some reason.