# How to change the text color when the button is being pressed?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am implementing something like the user interface from Microsoft Zune HD player. So, I would like to change the text color of my button when the button is being pressed as well as when it has been clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Case solved. I just added an XML file into my color folder. Add in a selector XML and change the attribute "textColor" of my button to that selector XML.

Further  reference - [Android selector & text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

In res/drawable, create a file called for instance `mybutton_background.xml` and put something like this inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_focus" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed" />
<item drawable="@drawable/button_background_normal">
</selector>
```

Then set this drawable as the background of your button with `android:background="@drawable/mybutton_background"`.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to change the text color but not the background as my background shall stay black no matter what state it is in.