# Can I partially change the color of this text in Android?

Tags: java, c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

[image]

I have a custom wheel picker view I'm working on as above. Is it possible to color the text that the blue rectangle highlights to white, even if just partially? So if it's 50% on the text, it'll change half of it to white, half to black?

**Edit:**

I'm using Java code (ported to C#) from here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-wheel/.

Basically, the blue rectangle is an xml defined shape that I place behind the scrollable text in code.

I then draw the rectangle, and the items on top, using this code:

```
/**
     * Draws items
     * @param canvas the canvas for drawing
     */
    private void drawItems(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Save();

        int top = (currentItem - firstItem) * getItemHeight() + (getItemHeight() - this.Height) / 2;
        canvas.Translate(PADDING, -top + scrollingOffset);

        itemsLayout.Draw(canvas);

        canvas.Restore();
    }

    /**
     * Draws rect for current value
     * @param canvas the canvas for drawing
     */
    private void drawCenterRect(Canvas canvas)
    {
        int center = this.Height / 2;
        int offset = (int)(getItemHeight() / 2 * 1.2);
        centerDrawable.SetBounds(0, center - offset, this.Width, center + offset);
        centerDrawable.Draw(canvas);
    }
```

From what I can tell, the rectangle itself doesn't have a text attribute to set properties like highlighting or ColorPrimaryInverse.

**Edit 2:**

From what I can tell I need to use Volodymyr's code in an overriden onDraw for each of the TextViews that make up my control. This is what I have so far:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        this.GetDrawingRect(rect);

        Paint mpaint = new Paint();
        mpaint.Color = Color.Black;
        mpaint.SetStyle(Style.Fill);

        canvas.Save();
        canvas.ClipRect(rect, Region.Op.Difference);
        this.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        canvas.Restore();


        mpaint.Color = Color.White;
        canvas.Save();
        canvas.ClipRect(rect, Region.Op.Replace); // lets draw inside center rect only
        this.SetTextColor(Color.White);
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        canvas.Restore();
    }
```

But this only changes the text color to white for all elements. I feel like I'm close here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to give a text (like 04:00) two colors (white and black)? I think it is only possible to color parts/characters of a text with different colors. You could try setting highlighted color like [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451347/change-the-color-of-highlighted-text-in-android) and see if the entire text changes or only the highlighted parts. You could also check the [textColorPrimaryInverse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textColorPrimaryInverse).

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'll look into those properties, but I don't think my code/xml is set up in such a way that makes that possible. I think I'll edit my question to show what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is couple ways to do that or something similar:

1. You can use the Canvas.clipRect method, pass the selection rectangle and render text with other color. So your code will be like:

   ```
   private draw(Canvas canvas)
   {
     RectF centerRect = new RectF(....); // change to your values

     drawCenterRect(canvas);

     canvas.save();
     canvas.clipRect(centerRect, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE); // lets draw everywhere except center rect
     drawItems(canvas, Color.BLACK); // Pass color outside selection
     canvas.restore();

     canvas.save();
     canvas.clipRect(centerRect, Region.Op.REPLACE); // lets draw inside center rect only
     drawItems(canvas, Color.WHITE); // Pass color inside selection
     canvas.restore();
   }
   ```
2. (Advanced) You can render text on new layer/bitmap and than combine it with ColorFilter like  to make the contrast.

Comment: I like this answer but would you be able to provide a bit more information relative to my two methods above? I'm still not quite following the graphics concepts.

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr! I'm nearly there but trying to work out how to set my text color? That all takes place in my adapter in a method called getItemText that simply sets the view's text color. Do I still change this property?