# how to change color of image in onTouch?

Tags: android

In my application i have one black and white image, now to want to change the black and white image into colored image like where ever i click on that image only that portion become colored

Thanks

Comment: There are so many ways this can be done, you've given no context as to how you want to do it. Is it a bitmap image on a canvas? Is it an ImageView etc. Try to put as much information as you can in your questions, you'll get replies that are more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this take  two different images one is normal image another one is focus image

main.xml code:

```
<ImageView 
                     android:id="@+id/emailsendimage" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:focusable="true"                   
                     android:src="@drawable/sendchat_normal_icon" />
```

next codefile:

```
 Submit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(hasFocus){
                             Submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.sendchat_over_icon);
                        }else{
                             Submit.setImageResource(R.drawable.sendchat_normal_icon);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Selector` for setting different images on different states.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) link out

Comment: It can be used for an ImageView as well. just put inside a 'drawable' folder (nor drawable-Xdpi) and refer to it in the ImageView like <android:src="@drawable/my_selector">

Comment: Maybe, but i don't know them. At last, you can always do the things with code.