# How to use Chips component from android support library?

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

I have read the documentation on the [official website](https://material.io/components/android/catalog/chip/). But I was unable to implement Chip in my project following the documentation. Android Studio can't find and import **Chip** class as well as **Chip** view.

I have also noticed that on [Google Developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html) there is no reference for Chip class.

There are some similar questions. But all answers point to use a third-party library. But I am trying to use Chips component from android support library.

Comment: That documentation is not for the Android Support Library. That documentation is for [this library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Comment: Then, how can I use Chips Component? Do I need to import something?

Comment: I do not see where they have documented how to use that code, sorry.

Comment: {
compileSdkVersion = 'android-P' //26
targetSdkVersion = 'P'
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.0-alpha1'
supportLibVersion ='28.0.0-alpha1'
} 
then add ChipGroup into layout 
NB: only works on Android P emulator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature is included in support library version [28.0.0-alpha1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#28-0-0-alpha1).
To use the feature:

In app gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
  
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
  // OR
  implementation 'com.android.support:design-chip:28.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

In Layout file:

```
<android.support.design.chip.Chip
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
    app:chipText="hello"/>
```

Guidelines : https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-v28-android-design-support-library-2c96c6031ae8

Comment: can we use this on production level?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using it (for production) until the stable release, since the apis may change in stable version from that of alpha versions. I guess the stable versions will be up soon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the material library

You can use material chip `com.google.android.material.chip.Chip` and `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` add in build.gradle

```
Filter style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"

Choice Chips style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"

Entry input: style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
```

[refer](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f)