# android how to apply shape and selector simultaneously

Tags: android, android-selector, inflate-exception, android-shape

I have been reading other posts where the solution is apparently given. However, the solution doesn't work for me. I would have commented in that post, but I cannot do it with my reputation.

The issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606995/android-how-apply-shape-and-selector-simultaneously-for-button). Basicly I want to use two different shapes dependign on the status of my ViewGroup. The solution marked as valid states the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>.......</shape>
</item>
```

Having implemented just that, I have an Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.mypackage.myapp.customviews.CheckableTextIconButton
```

There is one person (@toobsco42) that comment with the exact same problem, but he has no answer.

What could be happening here? Is there other way to use a selector and shapes?