# Android market like button using layouts and xmls

Tags: android, android-layout

Could someone point me to links and/or ideas on how to design a button similar to the android market "Install Button" using XML alone. i don't want to create something from gimp / photoshop and use it as android:src.

Please reference to the picture below from
http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57329887-285/get-the-ice-cream-sandwich-keyboard-on-your-android-phone/

[image]

If you notice the installed button it has a white rectangle stroke, black rectangle border, filled with blue.

[Note: the above picture does not belong to me, and link has been pasted indicating the copyrighted owner. The picture has been quoted as reference solely for the purpose of demonstrating the "installed" button and nothing else]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a linear layout with a white background, and a button with blue background inside. Give smaller values for button size, so it fits inside to leave some space so white borders are shown. User a selector for button, to change it's color in different states. More about selector [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color)