# Focus Table Row not working

Tags: android, focus, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout and i want the elements inside(each table row has a text view in it) to be focused ontouch. I set focusable attribute of each element to true but it does not work !

this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:gravity="right" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#444444"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <requestFocus />


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#993399"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >





            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Zein"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="About us"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Students"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Course Scheduele"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Exam Scheduele"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Exam Grades"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Course Grades"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="GPA"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Drop &amp; Add"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Petition Enquiry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00FFFF"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="University Services"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Petition Enquiry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#D60024"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Employees"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Petition Enquiry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#009933"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="My Account"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="Petition Enquiry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want each element to be focuses when the user touches it,
any idea why its not working here?

**drawable/table.xml**

UPDATE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#993399" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#993399" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#222222" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

and this is how am refering to it inside my main.xml

```
 android:src="@drawable/table1"
```

still nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

Create selector for your listview item, and set its parameters, for example:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/but" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/butpressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/butpressed" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

In the example I change the picture, but you can set any other parameter

Comment: can you please elaborate more I really did not quite understand what you stated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color
Here is the example of selector. the idea is to program different states of button. you may use the same idea for the TableLayout field

Comment: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
 at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:178)

Comment: You should define the image in selector in android:drawable  and set selector as android:src="@drawable/...". The exception you showed means that you've made an error in selector or in defining it in your xml-layout

Comment: It looks ok. Try to kill useless methods in your XML, problem might be in this. And you'd better use styles in order to make your XML readable.