# Change Preference Screen background color

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

I change color PreferenceScreen with this code.But how get Preference Screen in main Preference activity and change Preference Screen color ???

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(4, 26, 55));
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can override OnCreate Method:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(<COLOR>));
        return view;
    }
```

Or you can enter the following in styles.xml

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for your activity.

Comment: If i use Style.Components in ListView and screens don't work.

Comment: I set this style(android:theme) for PreferenceActivity.

Comment: <style name="Theme.White" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white_color</item>
     <item name="android:preferenceScreenStyle">@color/white_color</item>
     <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white_color</item>
 </style> and all PreferenceScreen black on scrolling

Comment: Did you assigned the theme to the activity in your manifest? <activity android:name="MyActivity" android:theme="@style/mystyle"/>

Comment: Yes, main preference activity set now white and work good, but preferenceScreens blink (black\white) on scroll =(

Comment: That is a `Selector` issue. Now you need to theme your selector for the screen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color

Comment: Help me please. I don't understand how fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just extend AppTheme and use colorBackground attribute

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the PreferenceFragmentCompat, the below solution worked for me.

SettingsScreen

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.ColorInt
import androidx.preference.ListPreference
import androidx.preference.Preference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import com.almarai.easypick.R


class SettingsScreen : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), 
Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

    //Providing the XML file for the view to be created
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_settings_preferences, rootKey)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    //Get the Theme specific color
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    val theme = requireContext().theme

    /*R.attr.colorBackgroundScreenBody is my own attr from attrs.xml file, 
    you can directly use R.color.red - Or any color from your colors.xml 
    file if you do not have multi-theme app.*/
    theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorBackgroundScreenBody, typedValue, true)
    @ColorInt val color = typedValue.data

    view.setBackgroundColor(color)

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```