# Common click effect for any android component

Tags: android, effect

My android application uses custom images heavily, it will be a huge work to design "effect" images for each of them, e.g. `clicking` effect and others.

I'm looking for an easy solution. For example, when I click on a clickable component, it will look grey, and when my finger leaves, it will turn to the original color.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color, check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use xml selectors. That will do!

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed" /> <!-- pressed/ clicked -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/image_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/image_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_normal" /> <!-- default / after release-->
</selector>
```

For more [check here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html).