# how to change image as long as button is pressed... and then showing default on button unpress android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to change imageview's image when user is holding button and change the image back to the default when user releases button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OnFocusChangeListener(view) method & override OnFocusChange() method to this.

Comment: button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
     imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
     imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.charging_1);
    return false;
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XML Selectors for this.  You can specify whatever drawable you want for whatever state you want.

The docs are here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

You will create an XML, that has references to each of the states you want to apply styles to, then you will reference when you assign a drawable to a view (a button for instance), instead of a particular drawable.

Check this SO question for more details: [Android selector & text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an `OnTouchListener` to the `ImageView` and in the `OnTouchListener` you can set the image you want to display in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and revert the old image in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Button class like this

```
public class MButton extends Button {
    public MButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public MButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // define style
    /**
     * Send resource ids for normal, selected, pressed in respective order
     * 
     * @param mImageIds
     */
    public void setDrawablePressedBg(Integer... mImageIds) {
        StateListDrawable bg = new StateListDrawable();
        Drawable normal = this.getResources().getDrawable(mImageIds[0]);
        Drawable selected = this.getResources().getDrawable(mImageIds[1]);
        Drawable pressed = this.getResources().getDrawable(mImageIds[2]);

        bg.addState(View.PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET, pressed);
        bg.addState(View.ENABLED_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
        bg.addState(View.ENABLED_STATE_SET, normal);
        bg.addState(View.FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
        bg.addState(View.EMPTY_STATE_SET, normal);
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
    }

    // define style
    public void setBackgroundPressedBg(Integer p1, Integer p2, Integer p3) {

        StateListDrawable bg = new StateListDrawable();
        Drawable normal = this.getResources().getDrawable(p1);
        Drawable selected = this.getResources().getDrawable(p2);
        Drawable pressed = this.getResources().getDrawable(p3);

        bg.addState(View.PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET, pressed);
        bg.addState(View.ENABLED_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
        bg.addState(View.ENABLED_STATE_SET, normal);
        bg.addState(View.FOCUSED_STATE_SET, selected);
        bg.addState(View.EMPTY_STATE_SET, normal);
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this in your onCreate Method

```
this.book_appointment = (MButton) this._view
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_book);

        this.book_appointment.setBackgroundPressedBg(R.drawable.btnnormal,
                R.drawable.btnsel, R.drawable.btnsel);
```

This will go like this in your xml layout file

```
 <com.packageName.custom.MButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_book"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_time1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bookapointment" />
```

Answer (score -1):

here in this post you can find the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18196156/2000517

Take care! ;)