# How to make selector keep the pressed state till clicked again

Tags: android, android-button

I use selector to create custom buttons with

```
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>
```

Now I want that the button acts as a state button remaining in the pressed status till is clicked again to return unpressed.

If possible I want to avoid to achieve this setting status programmatically.

Is there a way to do this using selectors (or something similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ToggleButton instead of Button?

**layout.xml**

```
<ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textOff="done"
        android:textOn="done"
        android:background="@drawable/test_selector"/>
```

**test_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- on checked -->
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_selected" />

    <!-- normal -->
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal" />

    <!-- pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Using ToggleButton with selector as background doesn't allow you to create more elaborate designs. A clickable layout is much more versatile.

Comment: you can do something like this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17274658/6578666