# Change the color of a disabled button in android

Tags: android, button, android-drawable

Is there a way to change the color of a disabled button in android through styles or some other form ?

I currently have the following,

**drawable/button_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default_shape"/>
</selector>
```

**drawable/button_default_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/button_default_background"/>
    <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
</shape>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_default</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomFontAppearance</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074623/4685284

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You'll have to use a selector for different drawables in those states.

You can create a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_enabled_drawable" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_disabled_drawable" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <!-- default state-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_enabled_drawable" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Very nice solutions

Answer (score 12):

Specify the color in selector for android:state_enabled="false" as drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#32ff09" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And apply this drawable resource to background of button

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/drawble_name"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Selector Applied Button" />
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE: For Android MaterialButton**

For Android `MaterialButton` there are two solutions, one for SDK >= v21 and another for SDK < v21.

Here I am also giving how to change the text color of the button depending whether it is enabled or disabled.

First create two color selector `.xml` file in your `color` folder. One for button color and another for button text color. For example `button_state_colors.xml` for button color and `button_text_state_colors.xml` for text color.

Here are those two color files:

1. `button_state_colors.xml`:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="#303F9F" />
        <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#BBBBBB" />
    </selector>
   ```
2. `button_text_state_colors.xml`:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#555555" />
    </selector>
   ```

Now for all versions of Android SDK you can change the color of button and it's text using style like:

in `style.xml`:

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.MaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_state_colors</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_state_colors</item>
</style>
```

in `layout.xml`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.MaterialButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Only for SDK >= 21 you can direct change button color without using `style` like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/button_state_colors"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this -

**drawable/bg_button.xml :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_focused" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_normal"/>

</selector>
```

After this just set background on your button like this -

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to achieve this is to create a **color selector**.

Create a file

```
res/color/your_color.xml
```

which looks like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorDisabledBackground" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorEnabledBackground" />
</selector>
```

Then you may use it as a regular color

in a style:

```
<style name="YourStyle">
     <item name="android:background">@color/your_color</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

As well is in layouts, shapes or in code as etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which works properly with button enable and disable state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_button_gradient"/>
   <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
</selector>
```