# EditText text color on highlighting

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-selector

How to change the color of the text upon highlighting it? Here is what I have tried:

**edittext_text_color.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/custom_blue"/>

</selector>
```

**some_layout.xml**:

```
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@drawable/edittext_text_color"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null">
```

**Normal state**:

[image]

**Highlight state**:

[image]

**What I want upon highlighting the text**:

[image]

Comment: Change some colors and see what happens.
and see this one http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html may helpful

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html check this one may it'll help to you

Comment: @PratikButani I've played with the colors a lot but that did not help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1280213/1318946 Tried out this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is supported. From what I see in [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java), there is no separate attribute for highlighted text, only for highlighted background. Text is drawn with text color states only, highlighted or not.

Also, `android:state_selected="true"` represents `ColorState` of a`View`, not of text inside it.

Comment: How about watching for highlight state and change the color dynamically?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad You can override `onDraw()` of `TextView`, find co-ordinates of highlighted text and re-draw that text (on top of everything `TextView` has drawn), with a different color.