# How to change color of text in ExpandableListView when is only pressed?

Tags: android, android-layout

In ExpandableListView I have custom parent row (LinearLayout) which contains row data (in TextView with id=data) andwhen is pressed (state before expanded) I change color of row.
How to change color of text when is pressed ?
I can in adapter set when is expanded and when is not pressed, but I cannot fetch when is only pressed.

Comment: create one selector for color and set to text of `TextView`

Comment: if you don't get my meant you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color

Answer (score 0):

You can set a selector as background of your `LinearLayout` :

Save this in /drawable/list_selector.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

And set it as background. Note that you can of course change the color as much as you want ;)