# Set color text RadioButton checked in RadioGroup with custom Shape

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have a problem, I can't change text color to RadioButton if it's selected.
I have this in  **activity.xml**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/activity_onsite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/onsite_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_btn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="office"

        android:button="@null"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/onsite_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_btn"
        android:text="clients"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:button="@null"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

in my resources **@drawable/togglebtn** I have

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_btn_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_btn_regular"    android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

And finally in my **@drawable/radio_btn_selected**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="5dp" />
<solid
    android:color="#39b3d7"

    />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#269abc" />
</shape>
```

And in **@drawable/radio_btn_regular**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="5dp" />
<solid
    android:color="#fff"

     />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#269abc" />
</shape>
```

Can I change text color in radio_btn_selected.xml?

Comment: you can create custom color selectors and set the text color with this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3565624/3092341 this may help you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't set both background & textColor attributes using a single selector. Create a new selector for textColor say **radio_text_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#39b3d7"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#39b3d7"/>
    <item android:color="#ff8a8a"/>
</selector>
```

Set the textColor attribute of RadioButton

```
android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selected"
```

Comment: This works like a charm, many thanks. "You can't set both background & textColor attributes using a single selector." This concept solves many other problems too.

Answer (score 1):

@sJy thankyou. It work.
I've added a **radio_text_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#f3f3"/>
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="#000"/>
</selector>
```

and on my **RadioButton** in **Activity.xml**:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/activity_onsite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    <RadioButton
        .
        .
        android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selected"/>
    <RadioButton
        .
        .
        android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selected"/>
</RadioGroup>
```