# Changing a Drawable file dynamically through mainactivity

Tags: android, background, textview, android-drawable

My problem is the following:

I have a *Mainactivity* class where I have a method, that gets a *TextView* with the *id* **colorselected**.

**Mainactivity method:**

```
  @Override
public void onColorSelected(int dialogId, @ColorInt int color) {
    this.color = color;
     findViewById(R.id.colorselected).setBackgroundColor(color);
    //om te tonen welke kleur geselecteerd is
}
```

**TextView in my first XML-file:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/colorselected"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/colorselecteddrawable"
    ... />
```

As you can see my *TextView* uses a drawable called *colorselecteddrawable*, the code in that drawable is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

I'm trying to set the background color of the *TextView*, whenever the `onColorSelected-method` gets executed. However, if I use the method as it is now, my *TextView* isn't round anymore, probably because the *TextView-backgroundcolor* gets **overwritten**, without using the drawable anymore.

So my question is: how can i change my *Mainactivity* method, so that I can change the `<solid android:color="..."/>` tag into the new color, whenever the method gets executed?

Comment: Could you check my answer ?Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

**You should add `android:shape="rectangle"` or `android:shape="oval"` in the xml code .**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: This didn't fix it :/ The first time it does change, but once i execute the colorselected method it just overwrites the drawable

Comment: You should add a shape for selected status .Then you can use it in your xml code .

Comment: And then you can add  `select.xml` for `shape` normal and `shape` selected .

Comment: And you can check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219312/android-selector-text-color)@PieterDesseyn